# CSS3 Validation Errors

Tags: css, validation, xhtml

UPDATED

I'm having trouble figuring out why my CSS is causing errors? I am unsure of how to fix these as I'm not that proficient at it. Could you please take a look and tell me whats wrong? Cheers I've managed to fix most of them but am having trouble with only 3 errors.

ERRORS:

```
109  .button, button, input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"], input[type="button"]    Value Error : background top is not a color value )
140  .button:hover, button:hover, input[type="submit"]:hover, input[type="reset"]:hover, input[type="button"]:hover  Value Error : background top is not a color value )
157  .button:active, button:active, input[type="submit"]:active, input[type="reset"]:active, input[type="button"]:active     Value Error : background top is not a color value )
```

My CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline; }
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
        display: block; }
    body {
        line-height: 1; }
    ol, ul {
        list-style: none; }
    blockquote, q {
        quotes: none; }
    blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
    q:before, q:after {
        content: '';
        content: none; }
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0; }



    body {
        background: #fff;
        font: 14px/21px "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #444;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 }



    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        color: #181818;
        font-family: "Georgia", "Times New Roman", serif;
        font-weight: normal; }
    h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a { font-weight: inherit; }
    h1 { font-size: 46px; line-height: 50px; margin-bottom: 14px;}
    h2 { font-size: 35px; line-height: 40px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
    h3 { font-size: 28px; line-height: 34px; margin-bottom: 8px; }
    h4 { font-size: 21px; line-height: 30px; margin-bottom: 4px; }
    h5 { font-size: 17px; line-height: 24px; }
    h6 { font-size: 14px; line-height: 21px; }
    .subheader { color: #777; }

    p { margin: 0 0 20px 0; }
    p img { margin: 0; }
    p.lead { font-size: 21px; line-height: 27px; color: #777;  }

    em { font-style: italic; }
    strong { font-weight: bold; color: #333; }
    small { font-size: 80%; }


    blockquote, blockquote p { font-size: 17px; line-height: 24px; color: #777; font-style: italic; }
    blockquote { margin: 0 0 20px; padding: 9px 20px 0 19px; border-left: 1px solid #ddd; }
    blockquote cite { display: block; font-size: 12px; color: #555; }
    blockquote cite:before { content: "\2014 \0020"; }
    blockquote cite a, blockquote cite a:visited, blockquote cite a:visited { color: #555; }

    hr { border: solid #ddd; border-width: 1px 0 0; clear: both; margin: 10px 0 30px; height: 0; }



    a, a:visited { color: #333; text-decoration: underline; outline: 0; }
    a:hover, a:focus { color: #000; }
    p a, p a:visited { line-height: inherit; }



    ul, ol { margin-bottom: 20px; }
    ul { list-style: none outside; }
    ol { list-style: decimal; }
    ol, ul.square, ul.circle, ul.disc { margin-left: 30px; }
    ul.square { list-style: square outside; }
    ul.circle { list-style: circle outside; }
    ul.disc { list-style: disc outside; }
    ul ul, ul ol,
    ol ol, ol ul { margin: 4px 0 5px 30px; font-size: 90%;  }
    ul ul li, ul ol li,
    ol ol li, ol ul li { margin-bottom: 6px; }
    li { line-height: 18px; margin-bottom: 12px; }
    ul.large li { line-height: 21px; }
    li p { line-height: 21px; }



    img.scale-with-grid {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto; }




    .button,
    button,
    input[type="submit"],
    input[type="reset"],
    input[type="button"] {
        background: #eee; /* Old browsers */
        background: #eee -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: #eee -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,.2)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,.2))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: #eee -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: #eee -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
        background: #eee -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: #eee linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%); /* W3C */
      border: 1px solid #aaa;
      border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
      -moz-border-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      color: #444;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 11px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      line-height: normal;
      padding: 8px 10px;
      font-family: "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

    .button:hover,
    button:hover,
    input[type="submit"]:hover,
    input[type="reset"]:hover,
    input[type="button"]:hover {
        color: #222;
        background: #ddd; /* Old browsers */
        background: #ddd -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.3) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.3) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: #ddd -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,.3)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,.3))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: #ddd -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.3) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.3) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: #ddd -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.3) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.3) 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
        background: #ddd -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.3) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.3) 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: #ddd linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.3) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.3) 100%); /* W3C */
      border: 1px solid #888;
      border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
      border-left: 1px solid #aaa; }

    .button:active,
    button:active,
    input[type="submit"]:active,
    input[type="reset"]:active,
    input[type="button"]:active {
        border: 1px solid #666;
        background: #ccc; /* Old browsers */
        background: #ccc -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.35) 0%, rgba(10,10,10,.4) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: #ccc -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,.35)), color-stop(100%,rgba(10,10,10,.4))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: #ccc -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.35) 0%,rgba(10,10,10,.4) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: #ccc -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.35) 0%,rgba(10,10,10,.4) 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
        background: #ccc -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.35) 0%,rgba(10,10,10,.4) 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: #ccc linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.35) 0%,rgba(10,10,10,.4) 100%); /* W3C */ }

    .button.full-width,
    button.full-width,
    input[type="submit"].full-width,
    input[type="reset"].full-width,
    input[type="button"].full-width {
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 0 !important;
        padding-right: 0 !important;
        text-align: center; }


    button::-moz-focus-inner,
    input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }




    form {
        margin-bottom: 20px; }
    fieldset {
        margin-bottom: 20px; }
    input[type="text"],
    input[type="password"],
    input[type="email"],
    textarea,
    select {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 6px 4px;
        outline: none;
        -moz-border-radius: 2px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        font: 13px "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #777;
        margin: 0;
        width: 210px;
        max-width: 100%;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        background: #fff; }
    select {
        padding: 0; }
    input[type="text"]:focus,
    input[type="password"]:focus,
    input[type="email"]:focus,
    textarea:focus {
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        color: #444;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
        box-shadow:  0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2); }
    textarea {
        min-height: 60px; }
    label,
    legend {
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 13px;  }
    select {
        width: 220px; }
    input[type="checkbox"] {
        display: inline; }
    label span,
    legend span {
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #444; }


    .remove-bottom { margin-bottom: 0 !important; }
    .half-bottom { margin-bottom: 10px !important; }
    .add-bottom { margin-bottom: 20px !important; }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with php?

Comment: You can use just `*` instead of writing out all those elements, if you are including every single one.

Comment: you shouldn't care about CSS errors..does it work as expected?

Comment: @vsync It works as expected but to me I want it to have no error's? I guess if that makes sense?

Comment: The validator somehow seems to have problems with the gradients... As vsync says... if it works, its ok...

Comment: You need to remove the `#eee` from the `background` lines which have prefixes. You also need to remove the "top" from each of them.

Comment: I would think you have missed a semi-colon off the end of a style attribute as it seems to be saying that somewhere background top is trying to be applied as a color value?

Comment: @TylerH That didn't work :/

Comment: errors in CSS means nothing, your wish for "not wanting them" is like wishing you don't want dust in your house because dust is considered bad. but in reality, dust changes nothing, and you just ignore it. so does css errors. They aren't "real".

Comment: @user3554003 Start again with just `background: #eee;` and then look up on CSSTricks or MDN or some place how to add gradients for each browser.

Comment: @vsync 1. That is a bad analogy, because dust *is* bad 2. That's false; CSS errors should be fixed/avoided on principle because poor, non-standards-compliant practices are what lead to this problem in the first place (needing different vendor prefixes, etc.). Please **do NOT ever** tell someone that bad CSS is OK. **Ever**.

Comment: @TylerH - many CSS erros can be ignored. I write advance CSS for 10 years now, and I strongly disagree with what you've said. what you think are "errors", sometimes aren't errors at all, just the parser which doesn't understand some of the syntax, and it just ignores it. for example, a Firefox CSS parser wouldn't understand what `-ms` is or what `filter` is. an IE parser wouldn't understand what `pointer-events` are, or whatever, you might want to invent your own CSS maybe? you can. and if dust is bad, then why are you sitting on it right now? hmm? live in vacuum if you care so much.

Comment: @vsync Your attempt at pedant-ism has gone unappreciated. Further, you miss the point; OP had real errors in his CSS. Neither of us would call `-ms` in Firefox an error, so I'm not sure why you're using that as an example.

Comment: no real errors. Don't get so scared of any shit the browser is telling you it doesn't approve of. again, CSS errors are mostly should be ignored.

Comment: I will just have to live with writing better CSS than you, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

To set linear-gradients you should use the `background-image` property. You can also set a background color to fall back to on older browsers. With this in mind, try something like this:

```
background-color: #eee; /* Old browsers */
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,.2)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,.2))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%); /* W3C */
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) for more info on using linear-gradients.